# Largest group table with all real irrep dimensions different

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Take for example the two groups $T$ and $I$. (See [character tables](http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/) - unfortunately chemists -like me- and mathematicians use different notation.) As you see, $T$ has three real irreps, and their dimensions $1,2,3$ are all different. In contrast, $I$ has five real irreps, $1,3,3,4,5$, $T_1$ and $T_2$ of $I$ both have dimension $3$.

Is there a largest (by order) $G$ such that the character table of $G$ has irreps with all dimensions different? (Since all these dimensions must divide the order, I doubt it. This should be easily answerable by the simple group classification theorem. Especially, for prime $G$ surely there is a largest one.)

Comment: I think you need to make the question you intend clearer.

Comment: Yes, the question is unclear and you would need to explain what you mean by all irrep dimensions being different. If by tetrahedron group you mean the group which is isomorphic to the symmetric group $Sym(4)$ of order $24$, it has complex irreducible characters of degrees $1$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $3$.

Comment: There was a closely related questions about dimensions of complex representations here (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79493/).  But if you ask about irreducible real representations that changes the problem. Already $M_{11}$ has irreducible (over $\mathbf{R}$) representations of dimensions $1, 11, 20,32,44,45,55$. Over $\mathbf{C}$, it has representations of dimensions (with multiplicity) $1,10,10,11,16,16,20,44,45,55$, but the representations of dimensions $10$ and $16$ are complex conjugate and the other representations have Schur indicator $+1$ and so are real.

Comment: @testaccount presumably the tetrahedral group is the symmetries of the tetrahedron, which is $A_4$, which has irreducible real representations of dimensions $1$, $2 = 1+1$, and $3$. (Since the question has been edited the question may well have been more confusing when you made your comment.)

Comment: @user491858: I didn't know before that there are such a thing as real and complex irreps (I'm a chemist first of all, we use mostly real irreps). Sorry for the confusion. And yes, A4, for a chemist T. (S4 would be Td, as we call something else S4...)

Comment: I like this question; I don't know why it was downvoted.

Comment: I agree with @user491858. To me the underlying question here is an interesting one (as the answer shows). It is phrased in a way that seems awkward to mathematicians, but the question-asker is coming from chemistry so that's understandable. I think MO should try to be more open to possibly awkwardly phrased but fundamentally interesting questions from outsiders.

Comment: I agree that the question should not have been downvoted. While some clarification about whether real or complex representations is meant (and what to do with complex conjugates), the question of “are there finite groups of arbitrarily large order such that no two irreducible representations have the same dimension?” is good and valid. (I would advise the OP to phrase it more or less like, however, that rather than asking whether there is a largest one.)

Comment: The complex version of this question was addressed in a paper of Berkovich, Chillag and Herzog (1992). In fact they only require that the characters of degree larger than one have distinct degrees. They prove (using the classification) that the group has to be soluble, and completely classify the possibilities. As far as I know, the real version has not been addressed in the literature, and it seems possible to me that a complete classification is achievable, using the classification plus some Clifford theory. The answer of @user491858 begins this path.

Comment: By the way, the dimension of a real irreducible representation doesn't have to divide the group order!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Now at least part of the way to an answer, also updated to include a monster mistake)

When group theorists study irreducible representations of a finite group $G$, they (without further clarifications) mean complex representations, that is representations over a complex vector space. This is where the theory works best. For example, the theorem you quote that the dimension of an irreducible representation must divide the order of the group is only true for complex representations; the cyclic group $\mathbf{Z}/3 \mathbf{Z}$ of order $3$ has an irreducible real representation of dimension two.

However, you can understand the irreducible real representations in terms of the complex ones. If $V$ is a real irreducible representation, then either $V \otimes \mathbf{C}$ is irreducible or it decomposes into two irreducible representations of the same dimension. This allows you to read off the dimensions from the character table as follows.

First, when you look at a character table, you will get a list of the characters $\chi$, which are the traces of the conjugacy classes of $G$ acting on $V$. There are three possibilities.

1. The character $\chi$ is takes on non-real values. If $V$ is the underlying representation over $\mathbf{C}$ as a vector space of dimension $d$, then one can view $V$ as a $2d$-dimensional real vector space, and that will be irreducible as a real representation. In this case, the character table will have another line corresponding to the complex conjugate of $\chi$, and these will correspond to the same real representation.
2. The character $\chi$ is real valued, and the Schur indicator is $+1$. In the character table, the Schur indicator is usually noted at the beginning of the table by (something like) $(+)$ if this is true or $(-)$ otherwise. In this case, the representation is real valued.
3. The character $\chi$ is real valued, and the Schur indicator is $-1$. In this case, just like in case $1$, you get an irreducible representation over $\mathbf{R}$ of dimension $2d$.

Some Examples:

If $G$ is cyclic of degree $p$ for $p$ prime, there are $p$ irreducible representations of dimension $1$. If $p=2$ these are both real (with Schur multiplier $1$) and of the same dimension. If $p$ is odd, then $p-1$ of them are complex valued if $p$ is odd, so there is $1$ real irreducible representation of dimension $1$, and $(p-1)/2$ real irreducible representations of dimension $2$. So you get a group of your desired type if and only if $p = 3$.

If $G = M$ is the Monster group, and $d$ is the dimension of an irreducible dimension (over $\mathbf{C}$), then $2d$ is not the dimension of an irreducible representation over $\mathbf{C}$. For any $d$ where there are multiple irreducible complex representations of the same dimension, either:

(i). There are exactly two such representations and they form a complex conjugate pair,

(ii). There are exactly three such representations, two of which form a complex conjugate pair and the other has trivial Schur indicator.

The latter occurs only for $d = 5514132424881463208443904$ (representations $123$, $124$, and $125$ out of $194$).

So $M$ is another group which satisfies your conditions.

**Update!:** Taking a closer look, I see that I negected to notice characters $\chi_{179}$ and $\chi_{180}$ which are both real with Schur indicator $(+)$ and of dimension $d = 136574874874360806036041889$, so the Monster group is *not* an example! In my defence, the typeface in the Atlas is very small...

Some Theory:

Let $\chi$ be a character of $G$. This is valued over an abelian extension $K/\mathbf{Q}$. I claim that either $K$ is $\mathbf{Q}$ or is an imaginary quadratic field. If not, there exists an automorphism $\sigma$ which is non-trivial and not complex conjugation. This preserves the Schur indicator for real valued characters and so by the correspondence above, $\chi$ and $\chi^{\sigma}$ will lead to multiple irreducible real representations of the same dimension.

A theorem of Feit-Seitz ("On finite rational groups and related topics") says that for groups $G$ all of whose characters have degree at most $m$, the composition factors of $G$ are all either $A_n$ for $n \ge 5$, cyclic, or lie on some finite list of other simple groups $\mathscr{F}_m$ (containing for $m = 2$, as we see above, both $\mathbf{Z}/3$ and the Monster group!) Now Feit-Seitz compute $\mathscr{F}_1$ (using the classification of the finite simple groups), but probably in this case one would want to start by computing $\mathscr{F}_2$.

Now I find that this set is computed in Theorem 4.7.2 here:

https://repository.arizona.edu/bitstream/handle/10150/621458/azu_etd_14762_sip1_m.pdf;jsessionid=6F9E69A3FEF036D4FEB281C483163493?sequence=1

So as a starting point, one can look at all these groups and see which of them satisfy the extra condition about distinct dimension; this gives at least the list of simple quotients of $G$, and then consider inductive arguments. (I assume from the hook length formula you can quickly eliminate the alternating groups, which leads to a finite number of simple quotients). I think the natural guess might be that there are only finitely many groups satisfying your condition, but any proof would certainly require the classification. My guess is that someone like Tiep may be interested in this type of problem and may well be able to answer it.

##################

OK, in the spirit of why not, here is what happens for the simple groups. The $20$ sporadic groups which need to be considered are:

$$M_{11}, M_{12}, M_{22}, M_{23}, M_{24}, J_2, \mathrm{Co}_1, \mathrm{Co}_2,
\mathrm{Co}_3, \mathrm{Fi}_{22}, \mathrm{Fi}_{23}, \mathrm{Fi}^{'}_{24}, 
\mathrm{HS}, \mathrm{McL}, \mathrm{He}, \mathrm{Suz}, \mathrm{HN}, \mathrm{Th},
\mathrm{B}, \mathrm{M}.$$

As noted before, $M_{11}$ is good (but the Monster is not). For the others:

1. The Mathieu groups $M_{11}, M_{22}, M_{23}$, and $M_{24}$ also all have
   the desired property, but $M_{12}$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $11$.
2. $J_2$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $14$ which can
   be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
3. $\mathrm{HS}$ has three irreducible representations of dimension $154$ which can
   be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
4. $\mathrm{McL}$ is interesting; it has two real characters of dimension $3520$ but exactly one has Schur indicator $+$. This group appears to have the required property!
5. $\mathrm{He}$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $1029$ which can
   be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
6. $\mathrm{Suz}$  has two irreducible representations of dimension $15015$ which
   can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
7. $\mathrm{Co}_3$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $253$ which
   can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
8. $\mathrm{Co}_2$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $31625$ which
   can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
9. $\mathrm{Fi}_{22}$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $50050$ which can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
10. $\mathrm{HN}$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $133$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
11. $\mathrm{Th}$ has four complex irreducible representations of dimension $6669000$ and hence two irreducible real representations of dimension $2 \cdot 6669000$.
12. $\mathrm{Fi}_{23}$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $56360304$ which can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
13. $\mathrm{Co}_1$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $469945476$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
14. $F^{'}_{24}$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $10776585600$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
15. The baby monster $B$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $10238958815085$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
16. The monster $M$ has two irreducible representations of dimension $136574874874360806036041889$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.

So the only sporadic examples are $M_{11}, M_{22}, M_{23}, M_{24}, \mathrm{McL}$.

The only cyclic group is $\mathbf{Z}/3 \mathbf{Z}$.

I *think* the only alternating group is $A_8$. The idea is to construct pairs of Young Tableaux (not pairs under the obvious symmetry) such that the hook length formula gives a repitition; so $S_n$ has $4$ representations of the same dimension; I think this implies the result for $A_n$.

Of the remaining groups of Lie type (whose characters are all defined in fields of degree at most $2$), it turns out that none have the required property. Here in each case (from the Atlas) are cases when things go wrong):

1. $L_2(7)$ has a complex representation of dimension $3$ and a real (Schur indicator $(+)$) representation of dimension $6$, so this fails.
2. $L_2(8)$  has four irreducible representations of dimension $7$ which
   can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
3. $L_2(11)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $10$ which
   can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
4. $L_2(16)$ has  eight irreducible representations of dimension $15$ which
   can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
5. $L_2(27)$ has  six irreducible representations of dimension $26$ which
   can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
6. $L_3(3)$ has  four complex irreducible representations of dimension $16$.
7. $L_3(4)$ has  three irreducible representations of dimension $35$ which
   can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
8. $L_4(3)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $26$ which
   can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
9. $U_3(3)$ has a pair of complex irreducible representations of dimension $7$, but a real representation of dimension $14$ over $\mathbf{R}$.
10. $U_3(4)$ has  four complex irreducible representations of dimension $13$.
11. $U_3(5)$ has  three irreducible representations of dimension $28$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
12. $U_3(8)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $10$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
13. $U_4(2)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $15$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
14. $U_4(3)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $35$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
15. $U_5(2)$ has  four complex irreducible representations of dimension $110$.
16. $U_5(4)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $10455$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
17. $U_6(2)$ has  three irreducible representations of dimension $1155$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
18. $S_4(4)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $34$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
19. $S_6(2)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $21$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
20. $S_6(3)$  has six complex irreducible representations of dimension $1365$.
21. $S_8(2)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $595$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
22. $O_7(3)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $260$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
23. $O^{+}_8(2)$ has  three irreducible representations of dimension $35$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
24. $O^{+}_8(3)$ has six irreducible representations of dimension $260$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
25. $O^{-}_8(2)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $204$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.
26. $O^{-}_{10}(2)$ has  two irreducible representations of dimension $5236$ which
    can be defined over $\mathbf{R}$.

Note that taking products of groups with this property will never work, since all of these groups have at least one complex character, and thus the product will always have at least 4 complex characters of the same dimension. So the summary is:

**Claim** (more detail needed for altenating groups) If $G$ is a (product of) simple groups all of whose irreducible representations over $\mathbf{R}$ have distinct dimensions, then $G$ is one of the following $7$ simple groups:

$$G \in \{\mathbf{Z}/3, M_{11}, A_8, M_{22}, M_{23}, M_{24}, \mathrm{McL}\}$$

These have orders $3$, $7920$, $20160$, $443520$, $10200960$, $244823040$, and $898128000$ respectively.

There is more work to do, of course. As noted, another example is $A_4$.

Comment: Lovely answer. I think that any group $G$ with the desired property must have $[G:G^{\prime}] \in \{1,3\}$- this is at least implicit in what you say.

Comment: PS: I agree that Tiep ( and maybe Malle and Navarro) would be interested in this question.